# Count of emails in a case

Tags: case

Is it possible to create a field on the case object that has a value of the number of emails a case has? With that, i want to create a field that gets populated when the count 3 (as in when an agent manually responds to a case (1st email is user submitting case, 2nd is case auto response, 3rd is the agent manually emailing out)

Answer (score 1):

As Email Message is not Master-Detail from Case, you have two options:

1. Create a Process Builder to count and create your rule
2. Code a trigger to count.

My suggestion, is using a Process Builder.

Comment: option 3 - Use DLRS

Comment: DLRS, is it? https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B45gWEAR

Good to know!

Comment: yes - also github which is where many get this (there's an auto-deploy button on the github page)